# How to change application root in a virtual url

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-security, virtual, spring-roo

From my university I got an virtual server, where I have my Tomcat installed. This instance is only reachable from within the local network, so the IT Admin also got me an forward URL to connect to tomcat from the outside. I deployed my Spring Roo project as a WAR file and I can see my `index.jsp` site.

Now I have the following problem:
From the outside I reach my project via the forward URL from `www.example.com/someDirectory/VM/8080/projectName/`
But spring_security refers to the root directory, so when I want to login I'm going to `www.example.com/spring_security`
Same thing for the generated links, the also refer to `www.example.com/link`

How can I fix this?

Comment: How is the forward made? With apache you could add the X-Forwarded header (which is what mod_proxy and others mods do)

Comment: to be honest, I don't know how he did it. It's completely out of my control

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is that you can't (easily) without some help from your IT Admin.

You need to know how they are reverse proxying the public URL to your Tomcat instance and then you are almost certainly going to need to ask them to make some changes. What those changes are will depend on how things are currently configured. You might also need to change the context path your application is deployed on to make the changes to the reverse proxy simpler.